# evaluation of conditions in an if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

Suppose I have this if statement:

```
foreach (MyModel m in SomeList)
{
   if (m.pID != SomeValue && (m.xID != 0 && SomeFunction(m.xID) == false)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

I only want `SomeFunction(m.xID) == false` to evaluate if `m.xID != 0` so if `m.xID == 0` then don't evaluate `SomeFunction`

For the moment, I have this if statement broken down into 2 statements and I'm looking to see how I can combine these into just one while preserving the logic. This is the original:

```
foreach (MyModel m in SomeList)
{
   if (m.xID != 0 && SomeFunction(m.xID) == false)
   {
      return false;
   }

   if (m.pID != SomeValue)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is all your loop is doing then I would be inclined to remove the loop entirely.

Also, instead of comparing something to `false`, just use the `!` operator.

```
if (SomeList.Any(MyModel m=>m.xID != 0 && !SomeFunction(m.xID) || m.pID != SomeValue))
  return false;
```

Comment: Is this Linq expression not going to be evaluated as a loop that'll iterate over every item? I like this Linq syntax BTW.

Comment: @frenchie: Of course it is. The point is that the loop is removed from *your* code. The benefit of LINQ-style code is that it makes your code express your *intent* rather than expressing *the mechanism*. If you were explaining the purpose of your loop to someone you'd say "the purpose of the loop is to return false if there are any items in the collection that meet these conditions".  The purpose of the code isn't the loop; the loop is just the *mechanism* that achieves the purpose. The LINQ code reads like your purpose.

Answer (score 5):

you are looking for this [|| Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)

```
if ((m.xID != 0 && SomeFunction(m.xID) == false) || (m.pID != SomeValue))
{
  return false;
}
```